# Large application architecture

Tags: architecture, soa

I am trying to architect a large .NET application with at least 16 or 20 modules i am implementing this using `Service Oriented Architecture SOA` so for now i have only 4 services implemented for only one module.

One of the four services is the `core service` which i need to be included in each module because this contains for example `Logging , Security etc..` i have no problem to include this in each new service.

I am facing a lot of problems that i need an advice in it.

1. Do i put all my `class libraries` in one solution or separate them in multi solutions for now i have about 40 class library.
2. For `database` I am now have one database do i separate the database too or let it in one database.

Any guidance for helping me in putting an architect for my application to consider using `SOA` and high maintainability also not to confuse development team with this large architect

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I get your question 100%. However, SOA services (and more recent micro services) are self contained and loosely coupled. In practical terms that often means, that services evolve on separate terms and should be deployable/testable in separation. I believe your project structure should reflect that.

I personally would go for two modules per service. Module A would be an interface specification that could be used in other modules that depend on the service. Module B would be the service implementation. I would have one service per project/solution composed of these two modules.

For databases: I think that every service should be responsible for it's own database. Of course you might share the database server between services, but each service should manage it's own database or at least schema on this machine. There should be no foreign key relations or other dependencies between the data of different services in the DB as these are dealt with via inter service communication.